# Is there an operator for function composition in Julia?

Tags: julia, function-composition

Say I have two functions:

```
f(x) = x^2
g(x) = x + 2
```

Their composition is the function

```
h(x) = f(g(x))
```

Is there an operator for function composition in Julia? For example, if `*` was an operator for function composition (which it isn't), we could write:

```
h = f * g
```

**P.S.** I know I can define it if I want to,

```
*(f::Function, g::Function) = x -> f(g(x))
```

Just asking if there is an operator form already in Julia.

Comment: Perhaps using the `∘` operator (enter using `\circ` TAB at REPL) will serve for a better math-y look.

Comment: @DanGetz Agree, but that is also undefined by default.

Comment: The route for getting to default would likely be: Define in your code -> In a package -> In a popular package -> In Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming here later. `∘` is available by default

Comment: Yes, since https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/17155 Julia now has the `∘` operator for function composition.

Answer (score 17):

It is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4963) to create such operator, but as now you can keep to the syntax:

```
julia> h(x) = f(g(x))
```

or a bit more clearer (for more complex functions):

```
julia> h(x) = x |> g |> f
```

It seems as for now you would need to keep the `x` for making it a composite function.

Another option, is to create your own operator (as you suggest):

```
julia> ∘(f::Function, g::Function) = x->f(g(x))
julia> h = f ∘ g
```

This works perfectly fine, however, it introduces a lambda function, and I cannot think a way of performing such operation without lambdas.

NOTE: ∘ operator can be written as \circ as @DanGetz suggested.

---

EDIT: seems [fast closures](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412) are coming in future releases and will probably be *easy* to implement an efficient version of the composite operator.

Comment: fast closures are now in Julia 0.5. Any updates on a composition operator?

Comment: This is now in Julia 0.6 (as  ∘ )

Comment: @Imanol As yours is the accepted answer, perhaps you would consider updating it with a note that `\circ` is now the composition operator? Thanks.